# Python RegExp, get group without certan word

Tags: python, regex

I have text like:

```
qwerqwer asdf foo bar
%abc anchor

one
%abc anchor

one thow foo bar
%abc anchor

one two three
%abc anchor
```

Now I have regexp `(.+)\n\%\w+\sanchor`, but it gives me `('qwerqwer asdf foo bar', 'one thow foo bar', 'one', 'one two three')` I want exclude from results string `foo bar`, and get result `('qwerqwer asdf', 'one thow', 'one', 'one two three')`

Maybe, somebody solved similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(.+?)(?: foo bar)?\n\%\w+\sanchor
```

You need to use reluctant modifier (`+?`) so it won't eat `foo bar` and also add a optional `foo bar` at the end of line

https://regex101.com/r/fU2jA5/1